# How to add an item to a global list var initted/wrapped in ObservableObject in parent view and have it reflect in ForEach in SwiftUI in a child view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I click a button in ContentView.swift, I expect the action triggering an 'append' to a sportList would show the newly added item.. but it doesn't. No compile errors. Clicking on the button does nothing (even though I can see the SportItem being packaged up correctly) in a print statement.

I created a model for an item "SportItem" that has simple properties (e.g. name: String) and a ObservableObject class.

```
struct SportItem: Identifiable {
    let name: String
}
```

I then create a global sportData variable  and an ObservableObject class outside of everything:

```
var sportData = [
    SportItem(name: "Tennis"),
    SportItem(name: "Basketball")
]

class SportList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sportList: [SportItem]
    init() {
        self.sportList = sportData 
    }
}
```

In SportListView.swift, I have inside of the body:

```
@ObservedObject var sportList: SportList = SportList();

...
ForEach(sportList.sportList) {
    sport in 
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Text(sport.name)
    }
}
```

SportListView is referenced in ContentView.swift, which has:

```
var sportList:[SportItem] = sportItems
```

that SportList() using:

```
SportListView(sportList: SportList())
```

I also have a button in the parent ContentView.swift file where I have a button where the action of it performs a:

```
SportList().sportData.append(SportItem(name: "Soccer"))
```

When I click on that button, I notice the SportListView in the simulator does not add the new item. How do I get the list to be updated to show "Soccer" added onto the list?

Comment: Global variables do not update SwiftUI view. You need to wrap sportData into view model following ObservableObject/ObservedObject.

Comment: I attempted to wrap with an ObservableObject/Observed object in OP, still isn't behaving like i am expecting. Could you check to verify the wrapping is right or post an answer that would help clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep `sportData` *inside* `SportList` (if needed via shared instance), like

```
class SportList: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = SportList()

    @Published var sportData: [SportItem] = [ SportItem(name: "Tennis"), SportItem(name: "Basketball") ]
}
```

and then

```
@ObservedObject var sportList: SportList = SportList.shared
...
ForEach(sportList.sportData) {
sport in 
   VStack(alignment: .leading) {
     Text(sport.name)
   }
}
```

and add like (if it is somewhere externally of view)

```
SportList.shared.sportData.append(SportItem(name: "Soccer"))
```